# Static unique identifier/column in SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to add a static unique value column to a view which holds its place and doesn't get changed when the view is called.

The idea is to have a unique identifier in the view, I'm aware of the fact that we can use one of the primary keys of joined tables as a unique identifier but in my case there are duplications of that primary key column value because it gets joined with multiple tables.

I tried **Rand()**, **NEWID()** , **ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))** they do serve the purpose but not completely.
Whenever the view is called they have different unique values, I need a unique value which represents a row and doesn't get changed when the view is called.

Looking forward to helpful responses.

Regards,
Ali Nawaz

Comment: You could concatenate (or otherwise use) all the PK values of all the tables involved - which is the logical approach. The idea of "a column" (singular) smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: By definition there must be at least one column with a primary key, otherwise you are needlessly duplicating data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "holds its place and doesn't get changed when the view is called" because the underlying data might change.

However, if you have some set of columns that uniquely defines each row, then `row_number()` should do what you want:

```
row_number() over (order by col1, col2, col3)
```

It is important that the columns uniquely identify each row.  Typically, these would be primary keys of underlying tables.